# "client.zadd is not a function" in redis nodejs

Tags: node.js, redis

I'm trying to use zadd function in redis its throws like an error.

zadd function not found in redis.

```
import { createClient } from 'redis';

const client = createClient({
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 32768,

});

 client.connect().then(() => {
    console.log('connected');
 }).catch((err) => {
    console.log('error', err);
    });
client.set('foo', 'no');

client.get('foo', (err, result) => {
    console.log(result);
}).then((result) => {
    console.log(result);
});

client.zadd('myzset', 1, 'one'); // client.zadd is not a function
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me,

```
client.zAdd('key', [{
    score: 1,
    value: 'a'
  }, {
    score: 2,
    value: 'b'
  }])
```

Answer (score 2):

Node Redis 4.x introduced several breaking changes including support for Promises. All of the commands were also changed to be either camel-cased or uppercased.

Try this:

```js
client.zAdd('myzset', 1, 'one');
```

Or this:

```js
client.ZADD('myzset', 1, 'one');
```

You can find the information about this [near the top of the README](https://github.com/redis/node-redis#redis-commands) for Node Redis.

Comment: I'm getting error, 

client.zAdd('myzset', 1, 'one');  // " Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'toString') "